# Delete duplicate record SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Please consider the scenario below

I have a table like below

```
Tag | Id | Client | ....and more columns
c     30    X
c     40    Y
c     50    X
c     60    A
c     30    B 
c     40    C
d     50    D
d     70    E 
d     80    X
d     90    Z
i     30    X
i     90    Z
i    100    X
i     40    M
```

I want to select records from table in such way that if tag=i 
the row below gets removed from resultset

```
  i     30    X
  i     90    Z
```

This is because the row with id=90  have already appeared with tag=d and client=Z.
But the row

```
i     40    M
```

must not be deleted even though id=40 has already appeared with client=C because client column value are different.

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE tag=i AND id IN( SELECT id FROM myTable t1
                      INNER JOIN myTable t2 
                      ON t1.id=t2.id 
                      WHERE tag=d or tag=c )
```

Comment: Why must `i    100    X` be deleted?

Comment: i have updated it .. `i 30 X` must be deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following `CTE` with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) to detect and delete duplicates according to your rule:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT [Tag], [Id], [Client],
    RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [Id], [Client] ORDER BY [Tag])
  FROM dbo.Tags
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1
AND [Tag] = @Tag;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6cb49/12/1)

Deletes these records:

```
TAG   ID    CLIENT   RN
i     30      X      2
i     90      Z      2
```

[**Over Clause**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick...

```
declare @Tag as varchar(10)
set @Tag = 'i'

  -- The select statement to view the record to be deleted
  select MyTable.Tag,MyTable.Id,MyTable.Client,RecordToDelete.totalCount from [SampleDB].dbo.[MyTable]
  inner join 
  (
    SELECT 
        [Id]
        ,[Client],
        TotalCount = count(id)
    FROM [SampleDB].dbo.[MyTable]
    group by id,Client
  ) as RecordToDelete 
  on RecordToDelete.Id=MyTable.Id and RecordToDelete.Client =MyTable.Client
  where RecordToDelete.totalCount>1 and MyTable.Tag = @Tag


  -- The delete statement
  delete [SampleDB].dbo.[MyTable]
  where MyTable.Tag = @Tag and MyTable.Id in (
      --select MyTable.Tag,MyTable.Id,MyTable.Client,RecordToDelete.totalCount from [SampleDB].dbo.[MyTable]
      select MyTable.Id from [SampleDB].dbo.[MyTable]
      inner join 
      (
        SELECT 
            [Id]
            ,[Client],
            TotalCount = count(id)
        FROM [SampleDB].dbo.[MyTable]
        group by id,Client
      ) as RecordToDelete 
      on RecordToDelete.Id=MyTable.Id and RecordToDelete.Client =MyTable.Client
      where RecordToDelete.totalCount>1 and MyTable.Tag = @Tag
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
DELETE FROM DUU
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT TAG,ID,CLIENT FROM 
    (
        SELECT TAG,ID,CLIENT FROM DUU A WHERE TAG IN ('I') AND  EXISTS (
        SELECT TAG,ID,CLIENT FROM DUU B WHERE TAG IN ('C') AND A.ID=B.ID AND A.CLIENT=B.CLIENT) 
        UNION 
        SELECT TAG,ID,CLIENT FROM DUU A WHERE TAG IN ('I') AND  EXISTS (
        SELECT TAG,ID,CLIENT FROM DUU B WHERE TAG IN ('D') AND A.ID=B.ID AND A.CLIENT=B.CLIENT)
    ) C WHERE DUU.TAG=C.TAG AND DUU.ID= C.ID AND DUU.CLIENT = C.CLIENT
)
```

Note : DUU is the name of the table .